# how to convert list type to double?

Tags: list, double, type-conversion

i have a list called cusList which consists of only one value which is a number,i want to convert this list to double data-type and assign it to a variable?how do i do it?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Would you attach a short example of what you have? That and the language would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What is the langue?

In C# it would be:

```
double d = (double)cusList[0];
```

In VB it would be:

```
Dim d As Double = cusList(0)
```